# retrieve all data by size of array in spring mongo template

Tags: arrays, spring, mongodb, size, gt

Suppose I have these:

```
{id: 1, name: name1, tags: [{id: 1, name: tag1}]},
{id: 2, name: name2, tags: []},
{id: 3, name: name3, tags: [{id: 3, name: tag3}, {id:33, name: tag33}]},
{id: 4, name: name4}
```

Then execute a query and I want this:

```
{id: 1, name: name1, tags: [{id: 1, name: tag1}]},
{id: 3, name: name3, tags: [{id: 3, name: tag3}, {id:33, name: tag33}]}
```

Getting documents that have "tags" array and its size is larger than 0. But don't know how to create my criteria.

I tried this but throws an error saying that size() has to take an argument of int...

```
where(tags).size().gt(0)
```

Anyone knows the correct one?

Comment: Can you share mongo shell query

Comment: db.collection.find({"tags.0": {"$exists": true}})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

['$size'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/index.html) operator doesn't accept the range parameters. You could use positional value existence to decide the size. [as follows](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hmWqQ-F4RRF)

```
db.collection.find({
  "tags.0": {
    $exists: true
  }
})
```

In Spring, You could try as follows,

```
mongoTemplate.find(Query.query(Criteria.where("tags.0").exists(true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$not](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator:

```
where("tags").not().size(0).andOperator(where("tags").exists(true));
```

---

```
db.collection.find({
  "tags": {
    "$not": {
      "$size": 0
    }
  },
  "$and": [
    {
      "tags": {
        "$exists": true
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

**Alternative:** You cannot create this with `Spring-data-mongo` framework:

```
db.collection.find({
  tags: {
    $exists: true,
    $not: {
      $size: 0
    }
  }
})
```